# Can't query relation count in Parse Cloud Code afterSave method

Tags: parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

I have an object class in Parse called Message that has a relation `installations` to many PFInstallation objects. I use this relation to keep track of which installations currently have local copies of each Message object.

I would like to check each time a Message object is saved whether there are a non-zero number of PFInstallations in each Message's `installations` relation, and to do so I am using the following method in Cloud Code:

```
Parse.Cloud.afterSave("Message", function(request) {
    var message = request.object;
    var query = message.relation("installations").query();
    query.count({
        success: function(count) {
            console.log("count = "+count);
        },
        error: function(error) {
            console.error("Could not count installations for Message": "+error);
        }
    });
});
```

However I am getting the following error message:

```
v8 after_save triggered for Message for user <redacted>:
  Input: {"object":{"createdAt":"2015-08-10T18:41:21.041Z","installations":{"__type":"Relation","className":"_Installation"},"isRead":0,"objectId":"N88D2m1bqB","recipient":"recipient@domain.com","sendDate":{"__type":"Date","iso":"2015-08-10T18:40:15.047Z"},"sender":"sender@domain.com","text":"v8","updatedAt":"2015-08-10T18:41:21.041Z"}}
  Result: Success
I2015-08-10T18:41:22.305Z]Could not count installations for Message: [object Object]
```

I have no idea why I am getting this error message or what the error `[object Object]` means. In other regular Cloud Code methods I have been able to count the number of objects in a relation just fine using a query like in the example above.

Please let me know what other information or clarifications I can provide to help answer this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the master key to read the Installation table. Try calling `Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey()` before running your `find()` query.